# Can you install Ubuntu directly to a HDD?

Tags: installation, 12.10

I was wondering since I am having problems with my computer's CD-ROM drive and Live-CD's, is it possible to install Ubuntu directly to the hard drive? For example, wipe the whole hard drive and burn the Ubuntu Install ISO to it, let the computer boot from the hard drive into the install interface, and then install Ubuntu on the same hard drive. Its far fetched- but is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: is a bootable USB out of question?
But I think its a bit far fetched indeed

Comment: Is HHD a typo, or are you talking about a hybrid hard disk/SSD?

Comment: a) The computer cannot boot via USB, and the LiveCD is failing me epically.
b) I meant Hard Disk Drive (the main hard drive) by HHD.

Comment: oh.. I'm sorry... I meant * HDD... oops

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure what is your problem. Can you boot using a live CD at all? If yes, you will discover you have the option to install Ubuntu on your hard disk from the live CD. If you have problems with the live CD and assuming your computer is new enough to boot from a USB stick, you can "burn" the CD image on a USB stick using a program like http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

In general, if you decide that Ubuntu is your OS choice, you should install it on the HDD. It will run much faster, not to mention that you will have much more freedom.

Comment: No... The computer cannot boot via USB. The LiveCD is failing... That's why I turn to this odd idea.. lol

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for other options beyond liveCD and bootable USB (somehow putting the ISO on your hard drive, booting it and installing to spare space from there sounds quite tricky, starting with the fact that you don't want to use your CD drive or USB).

Some alternatives are
1) A netboot install [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot), if your PC can network boot or has a functional floppy drive.
2) transplanting the hard drive to a PC with functional CD drive or USB for the install, before moving it back again - this would require some work tweaking GRUB, most likely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will look into a network install. How do you go about using floppy's? It has a floppy drive that it can boot from

Comment: Hi Sean - good luck to you with this. The information you need is at the [Ubuntu Netboot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot) page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot - I've never done it, so can't be much more constructive, but you'll need to make a boot floppy to start the netboot if your computer can't boot from the network card directly, as documented above.

Comment: I just read up on it. It looks like I can start the server on my Windows PC via Tftpd32 then create a floppy. I think that may be the anwser

Comment: If you have windows on there already you could install Ubuntu from within windows via [wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) - just thought I'd mention that for an effort at completeness.

Comment: Yes I read that, thank you. :)
My situation is I have a Windows 7 laptop and a 10 year old SONY desktop running Windows XP that I am trying to put Ubuntu on (since I find myself getting viruses off because he is a noob when it comes to computers.. XD ) . My problem is that SONY won't USB boot and at the LiveCD I keep getting the good old "(initrams) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system" error.

Comment: If the Sony has an internet connection (or can at least read the CD long enough to copy wubi.exe) and Windows XP I would go the wubi route myself - I believe that you can even wipe windows right afterwards if you like with `wubi-move`. Ubuntu will be a nice upgrade for the Sony - make sure that it has a 3D card or onboard 3D or maybe consider steering clear of Unity.

Comment: Tim, you just read my next question didn't you? :) That's what I was thinking next. It has a 3G connection via hotspot, the same one I share with my laptop I'm on now. Would it be possible to make wubi install Ubuntu from a seperare ISO image? (not a big deal, its just a matter of a nights electricity cost). And explain how `wubi-move` works. :)

Comment: I know it supports DirectX9, it was a very advanced PC in its day.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and came up with this solution,

Connect the hard drive to a normal windows/Ubuntu machine via a USB-IDE adapter, run Unetbootin and use it to create a bootable drive on the USB mounted hard drive.

Put the hard drive back into the old machine with no USB/CDrom drive.

Works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 1):

you cant install space what your first os installed . 
you can install on another part.
yes . but you need to make your hdd part bootable . 
and extract your iso to hdd . 
when you did all of thing you need install grup for booting .[grub install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)
and ubuntu is ready . when opened it select use from disk and open terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge ubiquity
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. My plan was to burn the ISO to a single partition that is 100% of the once empty disc. Then since the ISO when burned to a disc installs a boot loader (like when on a CD or USB) the computer boots, then I can make a separate partition to install Ubuntu on, and once that is installed delete the partition the ISO was on.

Comment: I!m sorry. i cant understand . do you want only ubuntu on disk or another thing ?

Comment: In the end the plan is to only have Ubuntu on the hard drive yes

Comment: if you want it you need delete windows part and deleting windows from grub . i will show how .

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:
If you have a computer that won't boot via USB in BIOS and the LiveCD doesn't work, download the ISO for a thing called 'PLOP Boot Manager' and burn it to a CD. Then, install the Ubuntu Install ISO image to a USB drive. Boot the computer via the PLOP CD and plug in the Ubuntu Install flash drive, then tell PLOP to boot via USB. Ubuntu then pulls up, and you can click the 'Install Ubuntu' option. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The boot process for a HDD boot is very similar to booting from USB. You should be able to write the Image for USB Boot sticks to a hard drive and use it like you would use an USB stick only attacht to the ATA Bus.

I believe the modern install CD is even an iso hybrid CD. so You can even write the iso file to the hard disk (like a partition image, starting with the first sector, overwriting the hard disks partition table).

I'm saying the ISO might work, but if you can, use the USB image anyway, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you think the installer would be cool installing Ubuntu on the same HDD that the installer is running on? And I know this is going to sound like a noob question, but does the Ubuntu installer have a function that installs GRUB on the drive so the system boots right to Ubuntu without me needed to install it manually?

Comment: Installing to the same Hard disk... hmm you would have to create an extra partition, and therefore a partition table, and i am not sure how the installer image will like that. could be that you have to overwrite a part of the images bootloader, but at this time the installer would already be in memory... crude hack, could work though. Same problem goes for installing grub. The Ubuntu installer does perform the grub installation automatically.

Comment: Yes... sounds like fun! >:D Since I have a USB Hard Drive reader, I was thinking of setting up the partition table via Windows and burn the image to a separate smaller partition and leave the rest of the drive open for the Linux install. The install ISO is 750MB and the system memory is 512MB, so the issue is I think the system will keep going back for the ISO. You know how to set it up so the system boots to a particular partition of the HDD?

Comment: Now this could be tricky... But wait. Is there a syslinux/ or isolinux/ directory on the CD? Syslinux and Isolinux are two related bootloaders, which use the same config file format but different first stages (i.e. MBR stages). In this case you could copy all files from the cd to a FAT partition on the harddrive. And then use syslinux to boot... and I don,t know how to install syslinux from windows. Ahmm... screw it, just try copying the image to a partition first, set the bootable flag for this partition and see what happens.

Comment: mm.. I think I shall! I will leave a comment back when I get a chance to get to it. This means I gotta find me a empty hard drive to play with. XD

Comment: Take your time, hope to see you again soon. From what i've seen on your website the community here (and the Free Software community in general) would be lucky to welcome you ;-), oh ... its 3 am here gn8

Comment: Oh trust me, I have been hard wired to DOS, so if I start using Linux your going to see me here alot.. lol. And thank you :)

Comment: Okay, Hola again XD
Just got a free hard drive on hand. I attempted to write the Image to the Drive.. that corrupted it. Luckily I have tools that fix that. Then I tried writing a FAT32 partition on it and copying all the files from the LiveCD to it. When I put that in my computer and tried to boot it totally didn't recognize it as being bootable. Help? Ideas?

Comment: NOTE^ The second time the drive was recognized in Windows the same the LiveCD would.

Comment: Okay, I got it installed! I used PLOP to boot up a USB install drive and put it on my hard drive. :)