# Install another distro from an iso while live booted into a different one

Tags: boot, system-installation

For whatever reason when I try to boot into linux Mint 17 from a live USB, I get a black screen with nothing on it after choosing which option to boot from (regular vs compatability). I suspect it's due to my optimus/nVidia card.

However, xubuntu 14.04 works. What I want to do is boot into a xubuntu drive and install mint onto my (unmounted) hard drive from an iso. I realize mint may not work once this is done, but I want to give it a shot.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to install Linux Mint again, from an ISO.

You can simply burn the ISO to a disc or thumb drive, boot to it, and install it wherever you like. You don't have to worry about booting into Xubuntu and you can even install it right over your non-working Mint installation, if you want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My bad, it's when I try to boot from the Mint installation media. I'm currently using xubuntu. Edited the question to be more clear on this point.

Comment: Gotcha, I fully understand you now. I am unsure whether that type of install is possible. This answer from a similar Ask Ubuntu question may work for you, though, I cannot confirm since I have not tried and it is for Ubuntu, not Mint. [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/207879/292342)