# How to re-run live installer?

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, ubiquity

I bought a new HDD today, and I'd like to make a fresh install of Kubuntu. Unfortunately, the largest storage device I have is 2gb, which is not enough to hold the graphical live installer. But wait! I have a fully functional, running ubuntu installation. Surely I can re-run the live installer, install to my new HDD, and be on my way?

Except... I can't figure out how to. I've grabbed the `ubiquity-frontend-kde` package, which I think [provides the installer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) I want. I tried launching it with `ubiquity`, `ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-kde`, and `ubiquity --desktop kde_ui`, guessing from [this stack exchange answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995980/how-to-install-ubiquity-to-full-install-bootable-usb). However, all my guesses either exit with code 1, or print some combination of the following lines:

```
/usr/bin/ubiquity:74: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
The value for the SHELL variable was not found the /etc/shells file

This incident has been reported.
```

The [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) is remarkably unhelpful on this front.

Does anyone know how I can run the live installer?

Comment: I believe your question is similar to this one:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/64504/if-i-can-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-ubuntu
and also this one:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/207871/can-you-install-ubuntu-directly-to-a-hdd

Answer (score 1):

Get an iso file that is small enough to fit in your USB pendrive, and that can do what you want.

- I would recommend using the Ubuntu Minimal CD alias **`mini.iso`** alias Netboot iso file, if it is OK to boot in BIOS mode.
- Otherwise, in UEFI mode, you can use an **Ubuntu Server iso file** which is also smaller than 2 GB, and install a minimal system.

When running the installed minimal system, run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

and reboot to get Kubuntu.

- You can find these iso files via the following links

  - http://releases.ubuntu.com - Ubuntu Server with the new style curtin installer
  - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/ - Ubuntu Server with the old style debian installer
  - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot - `mini.iso` with the old style debian installer

Comment: Hm. That would work perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @DDR, You are welcome and good luck :-)